# How Can I Do to my textbox autocomplete, works

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to do an autocomplete to my textbox, but it doesn't work. Follow my code.

```
    $(function () {

    var credenciada = '<%= credenciadaId %>';

    xml_NomeCompleto = "";
    var Nomes = "";
    var retorno = '';
    var count = 0;
    var t = '';
    $.ajax({
        url: "../Xml/AcessoExterno.aspx?Credenciada=" + credenciada,
        type: "get",
        dataType: 'xml',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {

            $(data).find("REGISTRO").each(function () {
                t = $(this).find("NOMECOMPLETOUSUARIO").text();
                Nomes += ["\"" + t + "\","];
            });
        }
    });
    $("#ctl00_contentConteudo_txtNome").autocomplete({ source: Nomes });
});
```

The variable 't' receives all the names of my users, normally, but the autocomplete don't work.

Comment: Have you run this through a Javascript debugger?

Comment: Yes, i put the 'debugger;' everything works fine, but still withou the autocomplete in my textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait for `ajax` response to complete and then initialize the `autocomplete` because before you initialize the plugin data is not available. Also the way you are creating Nomes(source) is wrong. Declare it as an array and use `push` method to populate it.

Try this

```
   var Nomes = [];
   $.ajax({
        url: "../Xml/AcessoExterno.aspx?Credenciada=" + credenciada,
        type: "get",
        dataType: 'xml',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $(data).find("REGISTRO").each(function () {
                Nomes.push($(this).find("NOMECOMPLETOUSUARIO").text());
            });
            $("#ctl00_contentConteudo_txtNome").autocomplete({ source: Nomes });
        }
    });
```

Comment: well, I put like this, but I can't see the result because is too slow...just loading...